# Can Behat be integrated with PHPUnit?

Tags: testing, phpunit, integration, bdd, behat

I have been setting up Behat in order to facilitate BDD as a testing framework for my company.  The ask is to also incorporate it with PHPUnit, so as to derive the benefits of that platform, with the readability of the Gherkin syntax of the Behat scenarios.

My first attempt at integration with PHPUnit was to make php exec() calls out to the command line from the Behat Feature file, and base the results of each scenario step on the feedback from that PHPUnit test.  This, however, feels cumbersome, and that there should be a way to more tightly integrate these tools, hopefully allowing Behat to call PHPUnit tests directly.

```
/**
 * @When <invoice_custcode>
 */
public function invoiceCustcode()
{
    $returnValue = "";
    $output = "";
    exec("phpunit BDDTest",$output,$returnValue);
    echo "returned with status ".$returnValue." and output=".print_r($output);

}
```

This far, the closest I have come is this project by Jonathan Shaw from 2019, but it doesn't seem to speak completely to my question.

https://medium.com/@jonathanjfshaw/write-better-tests-by-using-behat-with-phpunit-ddb08d449b73

Comment: I use both tools, but never thought of combining them. What do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: Hi Philip - I was trying to understand if I should call PHPUnit tests from the Behat FeatureContext file, so that the tests themselves could be written in the plain text Gherkin syntax, but call out to a library of stored tests that are contained in PHPUnit.  The reasoning was that this would provide the functionality benefits of PHPUnit and the simplicity of Behat.  This may, however, be looking at things the wrong way.

Comment: You can get all the benefit by moving your tests into Context files and creating feature files.

Answer (score 0):

The way to "integrate" phpunit would be to use it... the [behat composer.json](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/blob/master/composer.json#L32C8-L32C43) already includes php-unit...  and if you want to use mockery, just include that... and write your context to support your domain language features:

```
/**
 * @When I invoice code :invoice_code
 */
public function invoiceCustcode($invoice_code)
{
    //make mock
    $fakeDataRetriever = m::mock('My\Data\Api\Retriever');
    $fakeDataRetriever->shouldReceive('getData')->andReturn(['fake_name' => 'fake_value']);

    //test something with this mock
    $return = (new Something($fakeDataRetriever))->someFunction();

    //do an assert
    $this->assertSame($return, 'expected return value');
}
```

Then there are different hooks to do `setup` and `teardown` functions, except they are called `beforeScenario` and `afterScenario` hooks... and [there are many more of them for more control](https://behat.org/en/latest/user_guide/context/hooks.html).

Please [read the docs](https://behat.org/en/latest/) as behat offers a lot... for example [transformations](https://behat.org/en/latest/user_guide/context/definitions.html#step-argument-transformations) making converting text variables in feature files to object automatically.

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how people view phpunit as something "better" or "other" from behat.  behat does _everything_ phpunit does and more... meaning phpunit does a sub-set of what behat does.  The only difference between the two are that one is designed to present the features and scenarios in a way that allows communication with others... phpunit is only ever for a developer audience.